# Trouble installing R on RHEL 5.3 (Tikanga)

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, r, dependencies

I have installed epel 5 on my RHEL 5.3 distribution, and am currently facing issues installing R on it. Here's the error log:

`R-core-3.3.1-2.el5.x86_64 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libRmath%{_isa} = 3.3.1-2.el5 is needed by package R-core-3.3.1-2.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: libRmath%{_isa} = 3.3.1-2.el5 is needed by package R-core-3.3.1-2.el5.x86_64 (epel)`

But when I try to install `libRmath` manually, it shows that the required version is already installed:

`goelakash% sudo yum install libRmath
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Package libRmath-3.3.1-2.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

What can be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to enable `epel-testing` repo, according to the comments in this bug-tracker thread (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=1371184), that mentions that the latest libRmath has entered in testing repo, and is yet to get merged in stable.

So, the following should do it:

`sudo yum install --enablerepo=epel-testing libRmath`

You can also manually set the `enable` flag equal to `1` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo`.

`[epel-testing]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - Testing - $basearch 
.
.
enabled=0
.`

Set that enabled flag = 1.

Comment: Which is pretty annoying that someone pushed R-core to stable but not its dependencies.

Comment: I was more surprised at the fact that there weren't any other posts particular to this issue, as R is a fairly common software that is used by analysts across industry.

Comment: The problem is not with libRmath but with the R-core package which as buggered dependency. -3 package version of all R packages have been entered in epel-testing so `yum update --disablerepo=epel --enablerepo=epel-testing R` should work